# JQuery - Animate a Button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple JQuery button from a div which will change background color when rolled onto/off of.

My code so far looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Div Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("div").hover(function() {
                $(this).css({'background-color' : 'yellow'});
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #mainButton {
                color: #FFF;
                width: 100px;
                height: 50px;
                background-color: #333;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mainButton">
            <p align="center">Button</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, I can't get it to work. My button initially displays fine, but no yellow background on roll over. :-|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript should be this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("div").hover(function() {
            $(this).css('background-color' , 'yellow');
        });
});
```

and if you want the button to go back to #333 when going out of the button you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").hover(function() {
            $(this).css('background-color' , 'yellow');

    }, function(){
        $(this).css('background-color' , '#333');
    });
```

**EDIT to include animation**

This should animate the background color

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").hover(function() {
            $(this).animate({backgroundColor: 'yellow'}, 1000);
    }, function(){
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#333'}, 1000);
    });
```

The 1000 is how long you want the animation to take

Comment: }); should not be there after the first function :) besides that a good answer

Comment: That fixes my problem! I knew I overlooked something somewhere :)

How would I animate the background-color property?

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot for your help. Do you know any way of animating an element's CSS class? I want to define css types and have JQuery animate between them. Is that possible? eg: animate({"class":"defaultState"}, 400);

Comment: I don't think you can do that with the animate() method, but jQueryUI has a switchClas() method that does what you want.  http://jqueryui.com/demos/switchClass/

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're missing the [standard jQuery "wait for page ready" function](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready#fn) around your code.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   // Your code here
 });
```

and you only need the {} in your css function if you are modifying more than one key/value pair.

Answer (score 1):

Hover function takes two parameters:

```
        $("div").hover(function() {
            $(this).css({'background-color' : 'yellow'}); //mouse in
        }, function(){
           $(this).css({'background-color' : 'green'});}); //mouse out
```

[here](http://api.jquery.com/) you can find more details.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would use a `<button>` tag rather than a division tag with a paragraph element inside of it. The `<button>` tag is more suffice in what you are *actually* trying to do.

Second, you are using the jQuery `.css` function incorrectly. According to the [jQuery CSS Documents](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/css#namevalue), the script should be like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#mainButton").hover(
        // On hover over
        function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#FF0 ');
        }, 

        // On hover out
        function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#333');
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the existing answers, your solution isn't working simply because the element isn't in the DOM to even bind the event to it yet.  The suggestions use the:

```
 $(document).ready(fn)
```

syntax as described [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready#fn) to ensure that the DOM is fully loaded before binding events.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery to do this, though. You could easily achieve this via some pseudo class selectors with css.

```
DIV#mainButton:hover
{
   background-color: #ffo;
}

DIV#mainButton
{
   background-color: #333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the $(document).ready(function() { }) and you are using css function wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("div").hover(function() {

                $(this).css('background-color','yellow');
            });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of syntax errors and a missing ready()...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("div").hover(function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
        });
    });
</script>
```